# Minifying CSS at Wordpress output

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

one of pages which i work on, provides newsletter service by sending a generated page with listed posts and links to them. If we looked into source code of generated site, we will see a bunch of link for external css files etc., because of that some of mail software have problem with proper displaying that newsletter.

I can minify that code by copying generated styles to a file and trying to make site as much similar to generated one as its possible, but honestly, I don't have time for that.

It is possible to run, e.g some tool to scrap all used styles to one file? After that it will be much easier for me.

And the last thing - at this moment I dont have access to admin account on that page, so I cant use plugins.

Comment: Can you use https://gruntjs.com/ ?

Comment: Not really, never heard of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're emailing entire HTML to your subs, it's best not to include any files as they are likely to

1) get removed as most email providers strip JS/CSS before they hit inbox
2) get your email flagged as spam

Better thing to do is send out ENTIRE html (w/ inline CSS, and no JS).